# Nswag '{controller}' placeholder does not work with open api spec

Tags: swagger, openapi, nswag

I am trying to generate multiple clients for each controller using the {controller}Service class name option:

```
nswag swagger2tsclient /Input:api-swagger/api-swagger.json /Output:src/app/api/api.ts /ClassName:{controller}Service /WrapDtoExceptions:true /TypeScriptVersion:2.0 /Template:Angular /HttpClass:HttpClient /DateTimeType:Date /GenerateClientClasses:true /GenerateClientInterfaces:true /ImportRequiredTypes:true /BaseUrlTokenName:API_BASE_URL /InjectionTokenType:InjectionToken /RxJsVersion:6.0 /UseSingletonProvider:true /ExcludedParameterNames:Authorisation
```

While I expect a client for each controller, it only generates one client called Service, which contains all operations across all endpoints.

The spec file looks like the following:

[image]